# Symfony parameters.yml nfs mounted filepath changes to local

Tags: symfony

On the production server, my nfs mounted path is being translated to a local directory.  Any ideas what could cause this?

parameters.yml

```
parameters:
    files_dir: /n/fs/web/doc_root/Files
```

services.yml

```
app.file_manager:
    class: AppBundle\Services\FileManager
    public: true
    arguments: ["%files_dir%"]
```

FileManager.php

```
namespace AppBundle\Services;

class FileManager
{
    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $filesDir;

    /**
     * FileManager constructor.
     * @param $filesDir
     */
    public function __construct($filesDir)
    {
        echo $filesDir;
        $this->filesDir = $filesDir;
    }
}
```

Expected output: /n/fs/web/doc_root/Files

Actual Output: /opt/rh/httpd24/root/var/www/sites/web/doc_root/Files

Edit:

So it looks like in the container class file, appProdProjectContainer.php, the files_dir parameter is treated as a dynamic parameter.

```
$dir = __DIR__;
for ($i = 1; $i <= 5; ++$i) {
    $this->targetDirs[$i] = $dir = dirname($dir);
}

...
case 'files_dir': $value = ($this->targetDirs[5].'/Files'); break;
```

This breaks in my environment because the output of __DIR__ in the context of composer install on a command line is /n/fs/web/doc_root, but when running via apache the output of __DIR__ is /opt/rh/httpd24/root/var/www/sites/web/doc_root .  I'm able to delete the var/cache/prod directory and regenerate the container class file by accessing the site through a web browser or curl and it fixes my problem.  Is there a better way to do this?